# Visualizing Cayley's Formula in Mathematica

Tags: graphs-and-networks

[Cayley's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_formula) tells us that the number of labeled trees with $n$ vertices is $n^{n-2}$. Here is Wikipedia's visualization for $n=2,3,4$.

> [image]

How can we use Mathematica to visualize cases where $n > 4$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have upvoted @Szabolcs answer. I am sure there are better code to tree approaches than mine in the following. [IGraphM](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) is ideal as Szabolcs illustrates. I post this just to extend visualization for $n>4$ case.

**Happy New Year to all MSE users**

Just some visualization options:

```
fun[code_] := 
 Module[{v = Range[Length[code] + 2], cd = code, e = {}, c},
  While[Length[v] != 2,
   c = Sort[Complement[v, cd]];
   AppendTo[e, {cd[[1]], c[[1]]}];
   v = DeleteCases[v, c[[1]]];
   cd = Drop[cd, 1];];
  Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ AppendTo[e, v], VertexSize -> 0.3, 
   VertexLabels -> 
    Table[i -> Placed[Style[i, White, Bold], {1/2, 1/2}], {i, 
      v[[-1]]}], 
   VertexStyle -> 
    Table[i -> ColorData["Rainbow"][i/v[[-1]]], {i, v[[-1]]}]]]
disp[n_] := 
 Grid[Partition[Column[{#, fun[#]}] & /@ Tuples[Range[n], n - 2], n], 
  Frame -> All]
man[u_] := 
 Manipulate[fun[{##}[[All, 1]]], ##, ControlType -> SetterBar] & @@ 
  Table[{Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]], Range[u]}, {i, u - 2}]
```

So, `disp[4]`:

[image]

And `man[10]` (note this is inspired by [this Wolfram Demonstration](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/LabeledTreesOf10VerticesUsingPruferSequences/) but generalizes the visualization and I do **not** use the same code for creating tree from Prufer code). :
[image]

Comment: ubpdqn: Wonderful answer. Out of curiosity: did you make the video of you mousing over `man[10]` with Mathematica, or another tool?

Comment: @George ScreenToGIF

Comment: Happy New Year to all

Answer (score 21):

You can use Prüfer sequences to generate all labelled trees. [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) has the required functionality.

```
coloredPruferTree[p_] := 
  IGFromPrufer[p, GraphStyle -> "BasicBlack", VertexSize -> 1/4] // 
   IGVertexMap[ColorData[97], VertexStyle -> VertexList]

allTrees[n_] := 
  coloredPruferTree /@ Tuples[Range /@ ConstantArray[n, n - 2]]
```

Now you can list all labelled trees on 3 vertices:

```
allTrees[3]
```

[image]

Or 4 vertices:

```
allTrees[4]
```

[image]

Furthermore, you can group the trees by isomorphism class using

```
allTrees[5] // GroupBy[CanonicalGraph] // Values
```

Comment: A tiny comment on German orthography: When you don't have access to Umlaut characters, don't just leave out the Umlaut but replace it by a letter E. So Prüfer becomes Pruefer without Umlaut. That said, fantastic work Szabolcs!

Comment: @Roman Do you mean in the function name?  I actually thought for a while about whether to use `IGFromPrufer` or `IGFromPruefer`, then did a search to see what most other systems use. None of the ones I found were using `Pruefer` so I went with `Prufer` ... But then many of them don't even spell Prüfer correctly in their documentation, so perhaps I should have consulted a native German speaker. (In text / documentation I made sure to always put on the umlaut. I do care about it as Hungarian has it too.)

Comment: Yes, like [`GroebnerBasis`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroebnerBasis.html) computes the Gröbner basis, [`MandelbrotSetBoettcher`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MandelbrotSetBoettcher.html) and [`JuliaSetBoettcher`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/JuliaSetBoettcher.html) the Böttcher function, [`MoebiusMu`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MoebiusMu.html) the Möbius function, etc.