# Find all non-isomorphic trees with $n$ nodes

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks, trees

I would like to compute all non-isomorphic trees with n nodes efficiently. I use the following approach: I create all possible trees ( [Visualizing Cayley's Formula in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/212054/visualizing-cayleys-formula-in-mathem)) and filter the list of all possible trees.

```
fun[code_] := 
 Module[{v = Range[Length[code] + 2], cd = code, e = {}, c},
  While[
   Length[v] != 2,
   c = Sort[Complement[v, cd]];
   AppendTo[e, {cd[[1]], c[[1]]}];
   v = DeleteCases[v, c[[1]]];
   cd = Drop[cd, 1];];
  Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ AppendTo[e, v], VertexSize -> 0.3, 
   VertexLabels -> 
    Table[i -> Placed[Style[i, White, Bold], {1/2, 1/2}], {i, 
      v[[-1]]}], 
   VertexStyle -> 
    Table[i -> ColorData["Rainbow"][i/v[[-1]]], {i, v[[-1]]}]]]

checkIsomorph[start_ : {}] := Module[{outList, check}, outList = start;
  Function[{seedling}, 
   If[(check = FreeQ[outList, _?(IsomorphicGraphQ[seedling, #] &)]), 
    AppendTo[outList, seedling]];
   check]]

n = 5;
graphs = fun[#] & /@ Tuples[Range[n], n - 2];
selected = checkIsomorph[] /@ graphs;
```

Any suggestion on how to do it faster?

Edit:
I would like to be able to compute up to n=20.

Answer (score 4):

I am using [the IGraph/M package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM/) for this answer.

#### Approach 1:

Generate Prüfer sequences, convert to trees, filter duplicates based on canonical labelling.

```
In[17]:= Needs["IGraphM`"]

In[18]:= n = 7;

In[19]:= DeleteDuplicatesBy[
   IGFromPrufer /@ Tuples[Range[n], n - 2],
   CanonicalGraph
   ] // Length // AbsoluteTiming

Out[19]= {2.0961, 11}
```

**Update:** We can eliminate some equivalent Prüfer sequences by exploiting certain symmetries. For example, the numbers in the Prüfer sequence are effectively vertex indices. Shuffling the vertices would create isomorphic trees. Exploiting this, as well as the way `Tuples` works (which causes the first half of its output to be the same as the second half, up to relabelling), we can do

```
In[65]:= takeHalf[list_] := Take[list, Ceiling[Length[list]/2]]

In[66]:= n = 9;
ps = Join @@ Table[
    takeHalf@Select[Tuples[Range[k], {n - 2}], Length@Union[#] == k &],
    {k, n - 2}
    ];

In[68]:= DeleteDuplicatesBy[IGFromPrufer /@ ps, CanonicalGraph] // 
  Length // AbsoluteTiming

Out[68]= {3.3142, 47}
```

This is a very naïve approach. I am sure that thinking a bit more about what the Prüfer sequences of isomorphic trees look like would allow one to achieve much better performance.

#### Approach 2 (much faster):

Install [the nauty suite](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/nauty/) and use `gentreeg`. I have these tools installed in `/opt/local/bin` on my machine.

```
In[20]:= IGImport["!/opt/local/bin/gentreeg 7", "Sparse6"] // 
  Length // AbsoluteTiming

Out[20]= {0.020838, 11}
```

You can also do this with `Import` instead of `IGImport`, but it will be somewhat slower.

Comment: +1. I prefer the first variant.

Comment: @user64494 The second one just calls a purpose-made external tool to do the job, but it will be much, much faster. I highly recommend the tools from the nauty suite.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you for the answer. Your first approach is faster than mine but is the same in the concept. I am interested in the problem with $n$ up to 20. Your first approach doesn't work on my PC (and, of cause my one).
I am looking for another concept of solution, this is a reason that I do not accept your answer.

Comment: @KirilDanilchenko Why don't you use the second approach then? On my computer it takes less than a second and generates 823065 trees.

Comment: @Szabolcs I have trouble installing the nauty... I use Windows

Comment: @KirilDanilchenko You would need to compile nauty yourself. I would expect it to compile without problems with MSYS2. Unfortunately, Windows is not the ideal platform for doing research, especially in mathematical/theoretical fields: whether we like it or not, most non-commercial research software is written with Unix in mind. MSYS2 makes it at least possible to use a lot of these software on Windows, but it's still more trouble than it would be on Linux or macOS.

Comment: @Szabolcs yes...you so right