# List all homeomorphically distinct irreducible connected simple acyclic graphs of size 10 ("Good Will Hunting" problem)

Tags: graphs-and-networks, code-golf

In the movie *Good Will Hunting* the opening math problem is:

- Display all homeomorphically distinct irreducible connected simple acyclic graphs (trees) of size $n =10$

Recall that a tree (acyclic graph) is a graph without loops.  "Irreducible" means that there are no vertices of order 2... that is, no vertices that can be eliminated, its edges linked, and the rest of the graph remains unchanged.  "Homeomorphically distinct" simply means that the graph layout or embedding into the plane does not matter.  "Simple" means at most one edge between any two vertices and no "loops" (edges from a vertex to itself).  "Connected" of course means that there is a path from any vertex to any other vertex through the graph.

It turns out that there are 10 such graphs in the solution set, including these three:

[image: Three solution graphs]

What is the tersest *Mathematica* code that generates all 10 graphs?  The tricky part for me is the condition of irreducibility, as there seem to be no simple function calls to identify or eliminate reducible graphs.  `VertexDegree`, of course, will help here.

My preference would be for some generative algorithm, but I suspect the tersest is to generate many candidate graphs and select the solution graphs among them.

I'd love to have code that naturally generalizes to arbitrary $n$, but that isn't part of this problem.

Comment: When you say terse, do you mean short or concise?  I see 4 methods to solve this problem: (1) hard code the answers, (2) look up the answers, (3) generate and filter graphs with no rhyme or reason (i.e. random or all of them), or (4) actually solve the problem by generating graphs intelligently.  To specify any intelligent algorithm requires too many characters, if this is code golf.

Comment: Terse = few characters.  Seeking solution types (3) or (4).

Comment: Separately:  If Mathematica has an Inorganic-Chemistry module, you might get this by having it plot the set of 10-member acyclic isomers with coordination-numbers `{ =1, >2 }`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of doing a twisted form of search, like my other answer, this is a  perverted form of hard coding:

```
Join[KaryTree[10, #] & /@ {5, 6, 7, 9}, 
 ExpressionGraph /@ 
  Join[Groupings[7, {3, Orderless}],
   { 2π*a√b√c , 2a+3b+4c , 2a+b+d√c , a[2π(a+√b)z] }
]]
```

None of the whitespace is necessary.  It can surely be improved, but currently I count 124 characters (with π and √ counting once each).

The `KaryTree`'s get 4 of them, the `Groupings` get another 2, and I mash the 4 others in.

Comment: Alas, that code doesn't run on v. 11.3.  (I suspect ExpressionGraph is the culprit.)  
 But looks cool!

Comment: Blast!  Try with `TreeForm` instead of `ExpressionGraph`.  Would it still be valid with `Graph` and `Graphics` objects intermixed?

Comment: Yep!  Works... though the FORM of the graphs differ.  Clever (and fast), hence $\checkmark$.  Thanks!

Comment: IGraph/M has had `IGExpressionTree` since much before `ExpressionGraph` was introduced, and works in old versions of Mathematica

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, you can use ``GraphComputation`ExpressionGraph`` in version 11.3.

Comment: How do you like those Apples? ;)

Answer (score 14):

If you're willing to use some brute force, we can borrow ideas from here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/240803/4346

```
irreducibleGraphQ[g_] := Total[Unitize[VertexDegree[g] - 2]] == VertexCount[g]

<<IGraphM`;

takeHalf[list_] := Take[list, Ceiling[Length[list]/2]]

n = 10;

candidates = Sort[Join @@ Table[
  takeHalf@Select[Tuples[Range[k], {n - 2}], Length@Union[#] == k &],
  {k, n - 2}
]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {41.56, Null}
> ```

```
Length[candidates]
```

> ```
> 272918
> ```

```
found = <||>;
Monitor[
  Do[
    g = IGFromPrufer[k];
    If[irreducibleGraphQ[g],
      found[EdgeList[CanonicalGraph[g]]] = True
    ],
    {k, candidates}
  ],
  k
] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {33.9122, Null}
> ```

```
Graph[Range[n], #] & /@ Keys[found]
```

[image]

Comment: Great ($+1$).  I'll wait to see if anyone posts a shorter code before I accept.  Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

**Update:** TDIL from Eric Weisstein's answer that, thanks to updates to `GraphData` in versions 12.+, we can use `GraphData` to get the desired result fast and with a short code.

A variation to Eric's answer that shaves about 10 characters:

```
Select[# /@ #["Tree", 10]& @ GraphData, FreeQ[2] @* VertexDegree]
```

[image]

```
StringLength @ "Select[#/@#[\"Tree\",10]&@GraphData,FreeQ[2]@*VertexDegree]"
```

> ```
> 57
> ```

**Original answer:**

```
SeedRandom[3];

Union @ Select[CanonicalGraph @* UndirectedGraph /@ RandomTree[10,340], 
  FreeQ[2] @* VertexDegree]

Multicolumn[%, 5]
```

[image]

```
StringLength @ "SeedRandom[3];Union@Select[CanonicalGraph@*UndirectedGraph/@
 RandomTree[10,340],FreeQ[2]@*VertexDegree]"
```

> ```
> 102
> ```

We can get rid of `SeedRandom[3]` and increase sample size to get a shorter but slower version (which we might have to execute more than once to get 10 graphs):

```
StringLength @ "Union@Select[CanonicalGraph@*UndirectedGraph/@RandomTree[10,10^4],
FreeQ[2]@*VertexDegree]"
```

> ```
> 89
> ```

Comment: This is best (a hearty $+1$).... I should have known to wait for the extraordinary kglr's answer before accepting!  Mea maxima culpa.

Comment: Thank you @DavidG.Stork. Eric's answer using `GraphData` is both shorter and faster. It works in version 13.0. (In version 11.3.0 `GraphData["Tree" 10]` gives a shorter list of graphs).

Comment: you can always change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 11):

Brute force, and nondeterministic

```
NestWhile[l \[Function] 
 If[
    FreeQ[VertexDegree@#, 2] \[And]
    TreeGraphQ@# \[And] 
    And @@ Table[\[Not] IsomorphicGraphQ[G, #], {G, l}]
  ,l~Append~#,l
 ] &@RandomGraph@{10, 9}
, {}, Length@# < 10 &]
```

With `\[And]`, `\[Not]` and `\[Function]` counted as one character, I count 149 characters when removing the unnecessary whitespace (all whitespaces).

I swear it worked immediately on my computer :)

[image: all graphs]

Test with `Or @@ IsomorphicGraphQ @@@ Subsets[%, {2}]`

Comment: Great ($+1$).  I'll wait to see if anyone posts a shorter code before I accept.  Thanks!

Comment: What if we did not know beforehand that there are no more than ten of them?

Comment: Without this assumption, none of my answers are valid

Answer (score 8):

```
With[{g=GraphData},g/@Select[g["Tree",10],FreeQ[g[#,"Degrees"],2]&]]
```

Comment: But this doesn't solve the problem... right?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork unless I'm missing something, this answer produces the same graphs as the accepted answer.

Comment: @David, it works in version 13.0.0 (but not in version 11.3.0)

Comment: In 12.1 it doesn't output them all, so perhaps 12.2 or 12.3 makes this work.  I went and looked up the definition of terse in the dictionary -- this code is *terse*! (+1)

Comment: @JasonB. I took David's point to be that this doesn't *solve* the problem; rather, it *looks up* an answer to the problem. Personally, I think this answer is clearly relevant but I can see why David might not mark it as accepted.

Comment: Seems to work in 12.3.